# Exit MySQL script if database exists

Tags: mysql, sql, scripting

I have a MySQL script that I want to use *only* if the database doesn't exist to inject some initial demo data for development. If it does exist I just want to break out of the script. The script starts like

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `demo-database`;
USE `demo-database`;
```

Is there a way to exit here or above the create database if the database exists so that it wont run through all the table setups and inserts?

Comment: put the if before the create....

Comment: I'm still new to SQL in general, @TonyHopkinson, can you give an example? I've tried every combo I can think of with IF at the start and read the docs on the IF/THEN stuff, but I keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: here you go. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/

Comment: @tonyhopkins like I said in my last comment, I tried that. I can't seem to come up with a syntax that works for my use case. I don't think the CREATE DATABASE stuff can be an expression (from what I gather so far)

Comment: huh ? of course it can't be an expression. give me a minute.

Comment: In MySQL, you can't use `IF...THEN` structures in an SQL script, only in a stored routine. Most people write a script in python or something to do this. Any language can be used. Then they can use more flexibility in how they organize the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/schemata-table.html) to check the existence of Database

```
If not exists (SELECT 1 
               FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
               WHERE  SCHEMA_NAME = 'demo-database')

CREATE DATABASE `demo-database`
.....
```

Comment: Ive played with that a bit but I always get syntax errors. I also checked on a MySQL syntax checker site which also gives errors. But from my script with this in it I get `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 21: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE  SCHEMA_NAME = ' at line 1`

Comment: Oh and the caps `IF NOT EXISTS` was just me messing with it. I tried with your exact code copy pasted. My MySQL version is 5.6 (`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.21, for osx10.8 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`)

Answer (score 0):

What I believe now is that the construct with an if/else/endif can only be used in a stored program (see also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html)

I do not have a workaround other than creating a stored procedure that contains the code. In my situation I also have code I would to execute only on a test environment. I am creating only the stored procedure on test then as well.