# How exit a MySQL script if a database exists

Tags: mysql, if-statement, exit

I have a SQL script in docker, but I only want to run the script if it has not been run before. So, I though I would have something like:

```
IF dbname EXISTS
THEN
    exit;
END IF;
```

Looking around I managed to find code that will return 0 or 1 if the database exists:

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT SCHEMA_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA 
    WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'mysql'),true,false);
```

but I cannot figure out how to turn this into an exit statement

```
IF(EXISTS (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'mysql')
THEN
    exit;
END IF;
```

gives multiple syntax errors.

I am working with CentOS 6.7 and MySQL server 5.1.73 (forgot it is not MariaDB until CentOS 7)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734205/exit-mysql-script-if-database-exists?rq=1 which is unanswered

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean? Does the script create anything?
If yes you could use this trick:

```
IF SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA 
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'demo-database' then

  CREATE DATABASE `demo-database`
  // do other stuff ect

ENDIF
```

That might work. Atleast for me it did ;)

Comment: my SQL script creates the database and inserts data. It is almost 8000 lines, so I do not want to put the whole thing into an if statement.

Comment: This is the source of my confusion. If I enter your code in mysql interactive I get:
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'dem' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

After further thought and research, I think this is a limitation of the MySQL console. I was treating my SQL "script" as a script where it is actually just a list of commands. The IF statement in MySQL really designed to be part of a SELECT statement. So, I make this decision to run the SQL commands within a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than causing a certain action if the script exists, have your original action occur only if the script does *NOT* exist, such as

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBName;
///all the rest of your SQL,
```

This means the SQL will only run if the data structure is not already there. This looks like what you're wanting.